# Issue with Splash returning multiple html snapshots

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to return multiple html pages using splash scripts (in a single response, as in the documentation) and extracting the links from them. But I found that in the response.text and response.body, the html content is altered whenever there's more than one page returned. This is not the case with response.data, which works fine. Why is this happening?

I tried this on the same code (and website) as in the documentation- http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-html (from the later part, from the example for multiple html snapshots)

This is my splash request-->

```
 yield Request(url= url, callback= self.parse, dont_filter=True, meta={
     'splash': {
          'args': {'lua_source': self.lua_source, 'timeout': 200},
          'endpoint': 'execute',
       },
 })
```

The lua script looks like this -->

```
function page_info(splash, url)
   splash:go(url)
   local res = {
     html=splash:html(),
     }
   return res
end

function main(splash, args)
   local base = "https://news.ycombinator.com/news?p="
   local result = treat.as_array({})
   for i=1,3 do
      local url =  base .. i
      result[i] = page_info(splash, url)
   end
   return result
end
```

The resulting response:

response.data -->

```
{u'html': u'<html op="news"><head><meta name="referrer" content="origin"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="news.css?i7azI8MkFRPfcPhHQ7HD">\n <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">\n <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="rss">\n <title>Hacker News</title>
```

response.text and response.body -->

```
 u'[{"html": "<html op=\\"news\\"><head><meta name=\\"referrer\\" content=\\"origin\\"><meta name=\\"viewport\\" content=\\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\\"><link rel=\\"stylesheet\\" type=\\"text/css\\" href=\\"news.css?i7azI8MkFRPfcPhHQ7HD\\">\\n <link rel=\\"shortcut icon\\" href=\\"favicon.ico\\">\\n <link rel=\\"alternate\\" type=\\"application/rss+xml\\" title=\\"RSS\\" href=\\"rss\\">\\n <title>Hacker News</title></head>
```

Notice the extra \ \ in the second case. These might be escape characters or something, but they're messing with the LinkExtractor which uses the response.text and is resulting in broken links. Again, this happens only when I'm returning an array of html responses.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lua script is returning an array of results, which will be translated to a JSON-compatible structure in Python. The value in `response.text` seems correct.

The HTML you want to pass to `LinkExtractor` is at `json.loads(response.text)[i]['html']`, for `i` in `0..2`.

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: text = u'[{"html": "<html op=\\"news\\"><head><meta name=\\"referrer\\" content=\\"origin\\"><meta name=\\"viewport\\
   ...: " content=\\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\\"><link rel=\\"stylesheet\\" type=\\"text/css\\" href=\\"news.css
   ...: ?i7azI8MkFRPfcPhHQ7HD\\">\\n <link rel=\\"shortcut icon\\" href=\\"favicon.ico\\">\\n <link rel=\\"alternate\\" type=
   ...: \\"application/rss+xml\\" title=\\"RSS\\" href=\\"rss\\">\\n <title>Hacker News</title></head>"}]'

In [3]: print(text)
[{"html": "<html op=\"news\"><head><meta name=\"referrer\" content=\"origin\"><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\"><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"news.css?i7azI8MkFRPfcPhHQ7HD\">\n <link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"favicon.ico\">\n <link rel=\"alternate\" type=\"application/rss+xml\" title=\"RSS\" href=\"rss\">\n <title>Hacker News</title></head>"}]

In [4]: print(json.dumps(json.loads(text), indent=2))
[
  {
    "html": "<html op=\"news\"><head><meta name=\"referrer\" content=\"origin\"><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\"><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"news.css?i7azI8MkFRPfcPhHQ7HD\">\n <link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"favicon.ico\">\n <link rel=\"alternate\" type=\"application/rss+xml\" title=\"RSS\" href=\"rss\">\n <title>Hacker News</title></head>"
  }
]

In [5]: print(json.loads(text)[0]['html'])
<html op="news"><head><meta name="referrer" content="origin"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="news.css?i7azI8MkFRPfcPhHQ7HD">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
 <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="rss">
 <title>Hacker News</title></head>
```

Comment: You are a life saver! It works perfectly. Except, I had to construct a 'TextResponse' from the html before passing it to LinkExtractor (for it to work).